# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Product

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am following the railscasts tutorial. I have tried to replicate one of their tutorials which is about importing CSV and Excel file in to the rails page, but I am getting circular dependency error.

The following solutions are tried but didn't solve the issue:

1. Re-ordered the gems and bundle update / installed it
2. Downgraded my rails from 4.0.2 to 4.0.0

Any more solutions please. Thanks in advance.

View: ***test.html.erb***

```
<% provide(:title, 'CSV Import Test')%>

<div class="center hero-unit">
<h3> Test - CSV file import </h3>
</div>

<h4> Import .csv file </h4>

<%= form_tag import_products_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>

<h4> Products </h4>
<table id="products">
  <tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th> Tagnumber </th>
    <th> IsEnabled </th>
  </tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= product.id_pass %></td>
   <td><%= product.tagnumber %></td>
   <td><%= product.isenabled %></td>  
 </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

Model: ***product.rb***

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id_pass, :tagnumber, :isenabled

    def self.import(file)
      CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Product.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

Controller: **products_controller.rb**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def test
    @products = Product.order(:id_pass)
  end

  def import
    Product.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Data imported."
  end
end
```

Config: ***routes.rb***

```
resources :products do
  collection { post :import}
end

..
..
match '/test', to: 'products#test', via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, these gems work really really well:

https://github.com/liangwenke/to_xls-rails

They are very simple gems, but they make this task very quick. I wrote a clear a tutorial for rails 4 here:

https://github.com/liangwenke/to_xls-rails/wiki/Install%20Guide

You can also follow the authors instructions, but I found them difficult.

In your controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def test
      @products = Product.order(:id_pass)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.xls { send_data(@posts.to_xls) }
        # format.xls {
        #   filename = "products-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}.xls"
        #   send_data(@products.to_xls, :type => "application/excel; charset=utf-8; header=present", :filename => filename)
        # }
      end
    end
  end
```

In your view:

```
 <%= link_to "Excel", product_path(:format => :xls) %>
```